# If the diameter of the space station is more than 100 meters, can we let astronauts fly from side to side in the space station with their wings?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

If the diameter of the space station is more than 100 meters, can we let astronauts fly from side to side in the space station with their wings? Is it energy-saving, efficient, and training astronauts?

Due to weightlessness, it is difficult for astronauts to move in the space station.

The wings can be simply said to be a big fan in the hands of astronauts. Of course, wings can also be more complex.

Comment: What _wings_ are you talking about?

Comment: @josephh In short, it can be a big fan in the hands of astronauts.

Comment: It's possible, but it's also possible to let the astronauts dance the macarena while eating pistachio ice cream. Why develop random solutions when they can simply fly in a direction by pulling a rope or a handrail? More useless stuff on a space station (and NOT only on space stations, but also at home!) means a higher probability of having problems (maintainence, failures) and higher costs for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum width of the International Space Station is just over 100 meters, but this doe *not* mean that it is a sphere 100 meters across. In fact, it is more like a series of narrow corridors. [This infographic](https://www.space.com/3-international-space-station.html) includes a floor plan of the ISS.

Astronauts can and do launch themselves along these corridors, and with practice can move around the ISS very quickly and easily (in fact, staying still is more of a problem in microgravity than moving around). This [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06-Xm3_Ze1o) shows what the interior of the ISS looks like, and how astronauts move around it. I doubt than a fan would help, and artificial wings would simply get in the way and risk hitting important equipment.

Comment: Perhaps in the future, humans will build space stations with larger diameters. The space station you mentioned is only the current space station. Perhaps there will be a space station one kilometer in diameter in the future.